# onDraw() is called but nothing displayed

Tags: android, ondraw

I need to draw some rectangles on screen, over the background image. For this, I create this class :

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {

    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context,attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        System.out.println("draw");
         Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
         canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
         canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
    }

}
```

and on xml file of the activity I put :

```
<com.www.MyImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="150dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip">
```

In `logCat` I get the message down from `onDraw()` method but nothing is displayed. Where is my problem? What do I miss?

Comment: Change wrap_content to fill_parent

Comment: Thanks..that was the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

just try `canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, new Paint());`